# DateTime::createFromFormat How to set custom init date

Tags: php, datetime

At 2022-09-30 i encountered weird behaviour of DateTime::createFromFormat, for pattern **'Y-m' and date '2022-02' it returns 2022-03-02**, now i know this is happening cause php will populate missing date values.

But today i wanna write some test cases with pattern **!Y-m** or **Y-m|** but i cant reproduce the error because now is 2022-10-03 so `$d->createFromFormat('Y-m', '2022-02');` will not overflow to march, so can i somehow force \DateTime::createFromFormat to return value as if it was launched on 2022-09-30 ?

I also tried creating new instance of DateTime and call createFromFormat on it, instead of static call:

```
$d1 = new \DateTime('2022-09-30');
$d2 = $d1->createFromFormat('Y-m', '2022-02');
print_r($d2->format('Y-m-d')); // returns 2022-02-03, expected 2022-03-02
```

Also i am using php 7.4

Comment: With DateTime::createFromFormat you cannot set a custom initialization date.
Either the current date/time or the UTC base 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000 is used as the basis for unparsed components if a ! used in the format string. You have to create such a function yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Parsing an incomplete date and defining the missing components user-specifically is possible with the class [Dt](https://github.com/jspit-de/dt).

```
$dateFragment = '2022-02';
$dateInit = '2000-01-15 04:30';
$regEx = '/^(?<Y>\d{4})-(?<m>\d{1,2})$/'; //4 digit year, hyphen, 1-2 digit month
$timeZone = "Europe/Berlin";

$date = Dt::createFromRegExFormat($regEx,$dateFragment,$timeZone,$dateInit);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i');  //2022-02-15 04:30
```

The dateFragment returns only the month and year. A regular expression defines how the fragment is to be interpreted. Regular expressions are far more powerful than normal formatting. The missing information (day, hour, minute) is taken from dateInit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i was looking for solution which not require additional dependencies, but i will check this Dt class and how it is solved there.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of createFromFormat (https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) says that the arguments are in reverse order.

Comment: But how it solves my problem ?